# Override JE Quick Contact module in Joomla 3x

Tags: joomla, module, overriding

My client is using the module Je Quick Contact in their site, in Joomla 3.7.3
As default, the sender email is user's one, but in that way sometimes email goes in spams.
We would like to change it to have a generic send contact@domain.fr, seems we can't handle it in Back-office.

So I tried to override the module to change the sender email.
The module was in modules/mod_je_quickcontact and there there is files mod_je_quickcontact.php, index.html, mod_je_quickcontact.xml and folder CSS, JavaScript, PHP, images
In my template I created a folder mod_je_quickcontact and I put there all thoses elements, and I changed the file mod_je_quickcontact.php
But it's not working, it's still default data which are displayed.

I looked at Internet to see how to override, but for all example I found, in default module there is tmpl/default.php file to override. I don't have such folder and file.

Maybe I missed something or I did it wrong... I don't know what to do know, so, if someone has an idea, it would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in Joomla there is only a way to override a template or layout of modules. The module you used is not best practice, because there are not using a default template (`tmpl/default.php`) to display the output of the module.

Like in Joomla docs mentioned:

> The directory structure you need is: `TEMPLATE_NAME/html/EXTENSION_NAME/VIEW_NAME/FILE_NAME.php`

(Source: [Joomla override documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core/de))

What I would do: Copy the module, change it in the way you need it. That´s it.
There have to be a difference between paid and free modules :-P

Comment: Yes indeed I think there is no way to do it in a clean way, so I made a copy and change it directly in modules folder... Thanks !